# Why java services are static and final in WebMethods Integration Server

Tags: webmethods

I see all the Java services created are static and final in webmethods Integration Server? If all are static then why they didnt go for C as its procedural. I searched this question in http://techcommunity.softwareag.com and https://empower.softwareag.com but didnt found any answers. Can some make me understand why these static and final.

Answer (score 0):

A static method is simply one that is disassociated from any instance of its containing class. The more common alternative is an instance method, which is a method whose result is dependent on the state of a particular instance of the class it belongs to.

The key difference to understand is that a static method can be called without setting up a proper instance of the class it belongs to.In a sense, it is a stateless method.

you ask qus why they didnt go for C as its procedural?
c not object oriented programming language and whole project or program (online, offline) project not depend on two keywords static and final so they follows oops concept

Comment: Thanks Anil for your answer. Do you know why they made static and final for all the java services.?

Comment: @Inus not in only java  but C# vb other programming language also use static and final for webmethod and services. static and final don't want to instance object  it is a stateless method so we are using static and final.